# bibtex help cannot get capital II

Tags: bibtex

I have a reference with a capital roman II in the title.  When I run bibtex the capital roman II shows as ii.  How does on fix this.

Thanks,
Peaches

Comment: It is hard to guess what’s the problem without a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) ;-) so this is just a guess: Try to enclose the numeral (or the whole title) in a second pair of braces: `Title with {II} roman number`.

Comment: And of course: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score -1):

You may just replace `II` by `{II}` in your reference `title`.